# Intellij Database Tools - Derby Database

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby, database-tools

I am using intellij for a java project and am trying to use the database tools to create a local derby database but every time I try to create a database I get a error message `java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database '', see the next exception for details.`. Has anyone else ran into this problem or knows how to fix it?

Comment: What's the details given in the "next exception"?

Comment: Its list a list of exceptions. Its to big a list to cop in. Here are the first few. at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: Does it help if you select path manually and make sure to add a non-existend directory to the path?

Comment: No. The output is still the same.